# Sphinx: How to download extensions?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm getting the following error when I type `make html` in the linux terminal.

`Could not import extension sphinx.builders.latex (exception: No module named 'docutils.writers.latex2e')`

I then tried importing sphinx.builders.latex but it says it can't find it. Is there a way around this? Sphinx is up to date since I tried installing it and there were several lines saying `Requirement already satisfied` HELP!

Comment: Okay, so I went into conf.py and added the following into the extensions array. ```extensions = [sphinx.builders.latex.LaTeXBuilder]``` And now I'm getting errors saying ```builders``` is not an attribute of sphinx

Comment: Okay, so I saw that I shouldn't have done what I did in my comment above. I looked at the documentation and it says that sphinx.builders.latex should be built in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try re-installing latest docutils, might newer version need to work.

```
pip uninstall docutils
pip install docutils
```

I had same issue, worked for me.

Comment: A side note. If you have docutils downloaded through conda. Use ```conda uninstall docutils```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and installing `docutils` did not solve my problem. Here is what worked for me [[reference]](https://github.com/python/python-docs-theme/issues/45)

```
pip install Sphinx==3.1.2 sphinx.builders.latex
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, simply pip installing the missing extensions worked, i.e.

```
pip install sphinx.builders.latex
```